# How can I ensure low-resistance ground contacts to an aluminum enclosure?

Tags: resistance, grounding, conductors

I am building an electronics project with an aluminum enclosure. I need to ground it—and very well—for human safety. (The system handles 300 A of current, and I want to be sure that if there is an internal failure in the unit causing a panel of the enclosure to become energized, a fuse will blow rather than the panel becoming lethal to touch.)

Of course aluminum [forms a 4 nm layer of aluminum oxide within 100 picoseconds of contact with air](http://cacs.usc.edu/papers/Campbell-nAloxid-PRL99.pdf), and aluminum oxide is [an electrical insulator with a resistivity of 1x10^14 Ω·cm](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2006/EuniceHuang.shtml).

Putting those together means that there is a [31.5 megaohm resistance](https://www.google.com/search?q=10%5E14+%CE%A9+*+cm+*+4+nanometers+%2F+%28pi+*+%280.25+inches%29%5E2%29) between a piece of aluminum and a 0.5" conductive disc (such as a metal washer) in perfect contact with it if the aluminum oxide layer is intact.

I know that (for example) mechanically tightening things, particularly using a locking washer with teeth, can easily penetrate the aluminum oxide layer, but I am looking for industry specifications or best practices on choosing washers and torquing the connectors to ensure this happens. These ground connectors might also need be removed and replaced when servicing the equipment, and I want to provide specifications for reinstalling them to make sure this is done properly to ensure the aluminum oxide layer is pierced and conductivity is maintained.

As an example, I'd like to be able to write in the repair manual—with calculations based on sources I can cite—something such as "replace the lock washer with a new one, part number XXXXX, then tighten the bolt to YYYY Newton meters of torque, which will ensure an electrical resistance to the enclosure of less than 2.5 mΩ. Verify this by taking a four-point resistance measurement between test points 17 and 29, which should be 5.0 mΩ or less."

I'd also be interested in things such conductive greases, which I could put on self-tapping studs, that might work particularly well on aluminum to prevent the formation of the oxide layer, and could then be left in place.

Can anyone offer some pointers to resources I could use to learn best practices in working with aluminum as a conductor, and which I could use to develop a set of guidelines for repair and rework of electrical conductors in contact with aluminum?

Comment: Can't answer with the authority you need and desire. But the stud idea sounds promising. If the stud also has a kind of shoulder on it, it could actually serve as the contact point for whatever you are securing. So you have conductor in direct contact with non-aluminum stud, and stud in contact with aluminum chassis.

Comment: Could you possibly weld steel bosses to the enclosure?

Comment: When painting aluminum, there is a technique where you apply your epoxy based primer and then sand it while wet. This wet sanding breaks through the oxide layer, but since the epoxy is there, it cannot re-form. Don't know if that is an old wive's tale or not. But if you put some kind of conductive grease or just simple adhesive on a self-tapping screw, it seems like it would make good contact, and the oxide layer would never be a problem.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - The enclosure is made up of six separate pieces that need to all be grounded, and unfortunately we currently have no welding steps in our production process, so that may be cost prohibitive. But, aside from the cost issue, it's certainly an option to consider.

Comment: It doesn't take that much effort to break the oxide layer (because it's so thin), to prove it, place a coin on the metal and press lightly with a multimeter probe, measure the resistance to the aluminium with the other probe, you won't need to press hard to get a good contact, I've seen plenty of aluminium enclosed power supplies where it's just a tight shakeproof screw to the chassis, seems to work quite well.

Comment: @mkeith - The shoulder idea is a good one, and we'll surely do something like that if we go with the studs. As far as the epoxy/wet sanding thought, if there's a conductive grease on the market that lists such a procedure in its use cases, I'd be all over it! Or, more precisely, it'd be all over my studs. :-)

Comment: Found this, for whatever it is worth:
http://www.henkel-adhesives.com/product-search-1554.htm?nodeid=8802611593217

Comment: @Tom - I do not disagree. If I could find an authoritative source that states exactly that, I'd consider this resolved and move on. Perhaps the NEC mentions something about this. I've tried hard to avoid relying on any original research for safety design issues, as there are so many factors that are easy to overlook.

Comment: what you need to be asking yourself is not "is there a standard for this" but "how is this done in other compliant systems?" because if a product has passed compliance testing then their method has been approved, having read more than a few repair manuals myself, I can say that I've yet to see a section detailing citeable calculations on grounding bolt torque. Probably because anything more than finger tight will give you excellent contact and unless you're building a test jig for impulse testing industrial breakers (80kA impulse), there's not much to overlook, tighten bolt, check continuity

Comment: @Tom It's a system that handles 300 amps of current. I want to be sure that all the external enclosure panels are properly grounded so that if one were to become shorted to something due to an internal fault, a fuse would blow rather than a panel becoming energized and becoming potentially lethal to touch.

Comment: I don't think you'll find much literature on this as I can't see many potential problems, even if it was anodised (which would thicken the oxide layer), it's not hard to break it, 4nm is only around 30 atoms (Al atomic radium 143pm), you'll be able to get through that with your fingernail, the oxide isn't going to offer much resistance until it's several microns thick. In much the same way as you don't see guidelines on what temperature to solder power cables at for maximum conductance, this isn't something you need to worry about, work out what a tight torque level is and use that if you want

Comment: Well, now I know that your system needs to handle 300A, it's a little different, but not by much, large contact area, 5-15Nm should do it, most of the surfaces will be atomically rough and this will breakup the oxide layer when you tension the bolts. If you're still concerned, add some more bolts (redundancy is the name of the game), test it and/or speak to your appropriate electrical regulator, ce, rcm, ul etc. they may be able to give you some good advice seeing as they're the ones who decide what's safe

Comment: @Tom - Checking with UL and CE is a very good idea indeed. Not sure how much that might cost, but I'll consider that as an avenue to finding an answer to this. (I also edited my question to mention the current involved, just in case it affects future responses.)

Comment: They might give free advice. Keep in mind, even at 100milliohms, 300A will drop about 30V, which is not lethal but still a bit high for fault conditions. the most important thing is whether your connection can handle the full fault current which can easily exceed running current (3kA circuit breakers are tested at 80kA fault), as long as you've got something like a 1" by 1/4" bar (my 3000A spot welder has 4 1/2" bolts on a 1" bar) firmly bolted with several 3/8" or larger bolts, you'd be hard pressed to get any hazardous voltages on the chassis.

Comment: @Tom - I do agree with all of that. I'm mainly just hoping to find some formal guidelines somewhere. Thinking things such as of down the road, also, after years of thermal expansion and contraction of the bolts at a different rate than the aluminum, and the possibility of that opening a few-nanometer-sized gap allowing an oxide layer to form between that bar and the enclosure. (I know that thermal expansion/contraction and the use of dissimilar metals was the cause of many a house fire back in the aluminum wiring days.)

Comment: All I can say is: Use lots of well tensioned bolts and have multiple contact points, the more the better

Comment: This is a normal avionic equipment requirement. I would suggest looking at MIL-HBK-419A.

Comment: @PeterSmith - That is a ***fantastic*** reference. It includes mentions of torque (at least 40 inch pounds—4.5 Newton meters—just to initially break through the oxidation layer), as well as detailed diagrams of exactly how such a connection needs to be set up (top to bottom: aluminum bolt, steel washer, steel lockwasher, terminal connector, aluminum washer, aluminum structure, aluminum washer, steel locknut), and mentions of problems such as galvanic corrosion and types of sealants and so on. It will take some time for me to look through all of it, but I have very high hopes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to elaborate a bit so this becomes an answer.

Typical [avionic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avionics) equipment has a typical bonding requirement of 2.5 to 5\$m\Omega\$ around a chassis. There are different classes of bonding and earthing with their own set of requirements, depending on the threat and application.

There is an [excellent survey](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19980201283.pdf) from NASA on methods used over the years and the rationale behind them.

As already noted, MIL-HDBK-419A [Volume 1](https://www.wbdg.org/ccb/FEDMIL/hdbk419a_vol1.pdf) and [Volume 2](https://www.wbdg.org/ccb/FEDMIL/hdbk419a_vol2.pdf) contain a wealth of application assistance.

On the subject of oxidisation, it is common to use a [chemical conversion coating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_coating) to prevent aluminium from oxidising in both aircraft and on board ships; this has an advantage of reducing overall corrosion artefacts as a mated face could be the same metal as the new coating.

Note that [galvanic corrosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_corrosion) (also known as dissimilar metal corrosion) can be a major issue in aircraft, and we seek to minimise (or eliminate) it as it adds costs to the system operator because galvanic corrosion *will* eventually require repairs.

It is not always apparent that a great deal of assistance can be available for this type of issue, unless you just *happen* to be in (or have been in) one of the industries that require it.

Answer (score 1):

There are specialized washers designed to produce gas-tight connections through anodization layers.  http://www.we-llc.com/docs/librariesprovider3/default-document-library/code-compliant-weeb-info-for-inspectors.pdf?sfvrsn=0

I would be tempted to have the enclosure anodized, as I'm not sure that the Aluminum oxide layer is the equivalent of anodization.  I'm sure the makers of the WEEB washers could tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try capacitive discharge welding or short arc welding that is currently employed for steel electrical boxes and can be done also on aluminium. This is a very quick and sure system. Generally who builds boxes for electronics could do this, ask him. Remember also that alumina is very brittle and aluminium is very soft so when you tighten a bolt the local pressure breaks the layer and makes a good contact to base metal.

Answer (score 0):

Pure aluminum despite its natural oxide, doesn't need special treatment other than rigidly fixed mechanical hardware to make proper contact.

The high resistivity is strongly field dependent and only prevails with very small bias voltage. But the field in a nm thick oxide layer will be huge, even when there is only a Volt or less across it. At field on the order of 0.1 to 1 V/nm, even the sturdiest insulators experience total dielectric breakdown, i.e. start to form metallic filaments. In practise, it will be difficult to measure anything other than complete shorts between mechanically joint aluminum parts.

So it is not really possible to create lethal voltages when passing currents through joint aluminum parts.

However, aluminum with thick anodization is something that can develop very large voltages when you don't actively make sure, that you penetrate/remove the thick oxide layer as you mate the parts. This will usually not happen "by chance" for anodized parts.

As with anodization, if there is a thick scale on the metal due to exotic environmental conditions, the same precautions apply.